# compare two sounds in Adobe AIR app

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, mobile, air, speech-recognition

Can someone maybe help me with some information?

I'm building a mobile app and one part is a "speech recognition". The customer must read a sentence or a word should be compared with an embeded audio file? Is that possible in the app and Adobe AIR?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to do so with the help of a native extension: http://blog.immanuelnoel.com/2011/12/07/new-actionscript-native-extension-speech-recognition/

it will help you with:

- Provide an API to check if the feature is supported.
- Provide an API to launch the default speech recognition UI and capture voice input.
- Trigger events based on the success or failure of the above call. - See more at: http://blog.immanuelnoel.com/2011/12/07/new-actionscript-native-extension-speech-recognition/#sthash.xkDR999k.dpuf

By far I think it's easier and faster than making your own library that would run in AIR.

But do note that it's currently supported only on Android devices. You can of course make your own native extension for iOS provided you have the skills of writing Objective C/C apps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast responds, but unfortunately it must also work on iOS. Hopefully i can found someone who can help me with